# Current Program Status Register exception modes

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I'm working with code that has the following four assembly instructions:

```
CPSR_cxsf
SPSR_cxsf

CPSR_c
SPSR_c
```

I've been having a hard time trying to figure out what the difference between these exception modes is. Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`c, x, s` and `f` refers to the different parts of the status registers:

c = Control
x = eXtension
s = Status
f = Flags

The purpose of using e.g. `CPSR_c` is that it allows you to update only parts of the status register (in this case the control bits) without affecting the other parts.

Comment: +1 `c` -  define the current processor mode, interrupt enable and thumb mode (privileged). `f` - includes the `NZCVQ` condition bits that are used by conditional instructions.