# ARM Current Program Status Register (SPSR) read-modify-write strategy practice

Tags: assembly, coding-style, arm, cpu-registers

> The bits that Figure 2-10 identifies as Do Not Modify (DNM), Read As
>   Zero (RAZ), must not     be modified by software. These bits are:
>
> • Readable, to enable the processor state to be preserved, for example,
>   during process context switches
>
> • Writable, to enable the processor
>   state to be restored. To maintain compatibility with future ARM
>   processors, and **as good practice, you are strongly advised to use a
>   read-modify-write strategy when changing the CPSR**.

But with bitwise operations, you can already clearly define which bits you want to alter, without modifying any unexpected values, and it avoids wasting extra cycles. What's the reason of this recommendation?

Comment: There are specific instructions to avoid/reduce masking as well.  For example, `msr cpsr_c,r2`.  See also: [CPSR exception modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641149/current-program-status-register-exception-modes)

Comment: In your title you wrote SPSR (saved program status register), but I think you meant CPSR.

Comment: @Étienne That is true CPSR vs SPSR; they are different. But the underlying concept apply equally to both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the manual is warning you about is don't write zeros (or whatever) to the DNM bits assuming that they won't be modified - that may be the case in current processor implementations but even if that's the case today it might not be in future implementations.

Similarly, they seem to be reserving the right to change the RAZ bits in the future so that they might not always be zero or maybe that writing a one to them may cause some change in state, even if re-reading the bit still reads as zero.

Also, keep in mind that most bitwise operations that "clearly define which bits you want to alter" usually results in a read/write/modify sequence. For example, `val |= 0x08;` performs a read/modify/write.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way. Thanks for the clear explanation!